# handling generic HTTP exception with custom message in spring REST application

Tags: rest, http, spring-mvc, error-handling, exception

I am facing issues while handling HTTP exception in case of REST implementation
I want to display my custom Message to user in case of generic HTTP exception.
Trying to implement it using @ExceptionHandler annotation in controller advice, but that does not solve the problem.
I was looking into DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver but did not find any useful working example on the Net.

Can some one help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own application wide custom exception class, something like this.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException() {}

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

This custom exception can be thrown from any method then. For example:

```
protected void verifySomething() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    if(someConditionIsTrue()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Custom Message"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Rahul , i also did same way with custom exception but here i want to handle and show HTTP default exception example : if someone type URL www.abc.com/test  but it is Bad Request i want to show the user to explanation to the user